# Why doesn't this Technic bar fit?

Tags: technic, building

[image: made with stud.io]

Why doesn't this yellow Technic bar fit?

Comment: Looking at the holes of the horizontal bars at the right edge of your picture, it's easy to see that they are not aligned directly above each other. There's no reason to assume anything would fit that - and as Joost's answer shows, if you do align those bars it does fit (but the distance between the horizontal bars becomes "weird")

Comment: Since this is CAD, I think the underlying issue is that the beams are not placed at a 45° angle. Start with that (instead of starting with the placing of the parallel beams), and everything shall fit.

Comment: As Joost calculates the vertical distance the yellow bar spans as different from the horizontal distance it covers, the angle it creates with the horizontal bars can't be 45 degrees (in a configuration where it fits.

Answer (score 14):

It will fit, see photo. But you have to keep in mind that the distance between the two horizontal beams is not 4 units but will be sqrt(6^2 - 4 ^2) (Pythagoras), or ~4.47 units (the length is the distance between the holes, so 5 holes is the length of 4 units).

In the photo you will see that there is a gap of around half a stud between the brown 2x4 bricks.

[image]

Comment: And if you do want a right-angled triangle where the spacing between the beams is tidy so it joins up. it won't be 45°-45°-90°. Instead ignore the angles and pick a [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) to suit.  In this case a gap of 3 units horizontally and 5 on the diagonal will put the beams exactly 4 units apart (3,4,5, triple).  The next triple is (5, 12 13) which isn't as useful.